# SQL deduping help?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure there are a ton of ways to do this, but right now I'm struggling to find the way that will work properly given the data.

I basically have a table containing duplicates which have additional fields tied to them and source details that take priority over others.    So basically I added a "priority" field to my table which I then updated based on source priority.   I now need to select the distinct records to populate my "unique" records table (which I'll then apply unique key constraint to prevent this from happening again on the field required!)....

So I have basically,  something like this:

```
Select phone, carrier, src, priority
from dbo.mytable
```

**So basically I need to pull distinct on phone in order of priority (1,2,3,4, etc), and basically pull the rest of the other data along with it and still keep UNIQUE on phone.**

I've tried a few things using sub-select from the same table with min(priority) value, but outcome still doesn't seem to make sense.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

*EDIT* I need to dedupe from the same table, but I can populate a new table with the uniques if needed based on my select statement to pull the uniques.   This is in MSSQL, but figured anyone with SQL knowledge could answer.

For example, let's say I have the following rows:

```
5556667777, ATT, source1, 1
5556667777, ATT, source2, 2
5556667777, ATT, source3, 3
```

I need to pull uniques based on priority 1 first..... the problem is, I need to remove any all other dupes from the table based on the priority order without ending up with the same phone number twice again.   Make sense?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Are we talking about just one table here? Do you want to *remove* duplicate records, or just to have a query not return duplicates? And what exactly *is* a duplicate anyways? Also why is this tagged both `[mysql]` and `[tsql]`?

Comment: Is this in MySQL or MSSQL/Sybase? TSQL is different from standard SQL.

Comment: do you want the unique phone entries with a certain priority? I don't quite understand the problem yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're saying the combination (phone, priority) is unique in the existing table, and you want to select the rows for which the priority is smallest?

```
SELECT mytable.phone, mytable.carrier, mytable.src
  FROM mytable
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT phone, MIN(priority) AS minpriority
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY phone
  ) AS minphone
  ON mytable.phone = minphone.phone
  AND mytable.priority = minphone.minpriority
```